# Unsorting the sorting object in Hashtable

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap

I have the Hashtable object ,In which i added the keys and values.

The values in the Hashtable is an ArrayList.

Now the problem is that i sorted the Hashtable values using the below method by iterating.

```
 Collections.sort(keys)
```

After sorting , the changes done.Again i want the another copy of unsorted values from the hashtable. Even i tried another hashtable object but the sorted one done globally on the first hashtable object .How to get unsorted value from the hashtable by creating another Hashtable object.

Suppose my question is not understandable,Let me know !! i will add that too !!

Thanks !!!

Comment: Before sorting you can make a clone of unsorted object.

Comment: Eventhough i cloned as you said, it is not working!!!

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: Actually my hashtable values i.e) arrayList.So whether i need to take a copy of ArrayList instead of hashtable ???

Comment: Yes, I just write one code as per requirement and it seems you need to clone ArrayList as well as if we clone we get the cloned object of Map and as ArrayList is reference type so the ArrayList inside cloned HashMap is still pointing to the previously created objects of ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

you can use xxx.clone(); method to get the copy of hashmap before sorting.

```
  (HashMap)yourHashMap.clone();
```

Comment: Actually my hashtable values i.e) arrayList.So whether i need to take a copy of ArrayList instead of hashtable ???

Answer (score 0):

Clone will not work here and default clone does a 'shallow cloning'. Hence, the original and the cloned maps will contain references to the same lists.

An alternative approach can be to serialize the hashmap, and then deserialize it. This can garunty and deep clone.

OR

You can manually create the duplicate map by iterating over keys of map and over elements of the collection.

Comment: Creating duplicate map makes performance hit..i have around 10thousand Strings.Again iterating over is tedious process ?

Comment: In that case keep only two copies of the map. One is original, and another one is one you create by serializing and dEserializing the original map. Just two copies. Reuse and recycle.

Comment: create cloned arraylist and then make new similar hash map.